# StorageClientException azure table query

Tags: azure-table-storage

I am doing some querying to azure table using async queries. i get StorageClientException when i ask for rows in interval time frame of 4 hours.

the exception messge is:
Unexpected internal storage client error.

StackTrace is:

at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.TaskAsyncResult`1.EndInvoke() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TaskImplHelper.EndImpl[T](IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TaskImplHelper.EndImplWithRetry[T](IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudTableQuery`1.EndExecuteSegmented(IAsyncResult asyncResult)   the error came from the following method call : CloudTableQuery EndExecuteSegmented(result)

Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: just to make things clear i am doing multiple queries at each time

Answer (score 0):

probably you are using a not supported method or operation

check this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135725.aspx